# Overriding a concern of a gem - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, overriding

I am trying to modify a gem (Devise token auth to be precise) to suit my needs. For that I want to override certain functions inside the concern SetUserByToken.

The problem is how do I override that?

I don't want to change the gem files. Is there an easy/standard way of doing that?

Answer (score 5):

Bear in mind here that a "concern" in Rails is just a module with a few programmer conveniences from [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

When you include a module in a class the methods defined in the class itself will have priority over the included module.

```
module Greeter
  def hello
    "hello world"
  end
end

class LeetSpeaker
  include Greeter
  def hello 
    super.tr("e", "3").tr("o", "0")
  end
end

LeetSpeaker.new.hello # => "h3ll0 w0rld"
```

So you can quite simply redefine the needed methods in `ApplicationController` or even compose a module of your own of your own without monkey patching the library:

```
module Greeter
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def hello
    "hello world"
  end

  class_methods do
     def foo
       "bar"
     end
  end
end

module BetterGreeter
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def hello
    super.titlecase
  end

  # we can override class methods as well.
  class_methods do
     def foo
       "baz"
     end
  end
end

class Person
  include Greeter # the order of inclusion matters
  include BetterGreeter
end

Person.new.hello # => "Hello World"
Person.foo # => "baz"
```

See [Monkey patching: the good, the bad and the ugly](http://cosent.nl/en/blog/monkey-patching-good-bad-ugly) for a good explanation why it often is better to overlay your custom code on top of a framework or library rather than modifying a library component at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can monkey patch concerns like any other module:

```
module DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  # Your code here
end
```

If you want to extend the behavior of an existing method, try using an *around alias*:

http://rubyquicktips.com/post/18427759343/around-alias