# How to override concern in devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-token-auth

I use `devise_token_auth` gem. And I want override concern `resource_finder.rb` for modify method `provider`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding a concern of a gem - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37237434/overriding-a-concern-of-a-gem-rails)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, in which I wanted to override an method in `concerns/user.rb`
I had already a `user.rb` in my `models/` directory, I simply added a method with same name in my `model/user.rb` file and it worked

For you, you can create `resource_finder.rb` under `models/` which will we override `devise_token_auth` `concerns/resource_finder.rb`